# Solving Hibernate issues migrating from Glassfish to TomEE. Datasource is created, then destroyed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, apache-tomee

We have run into the [#22224 bug](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22224) trying to migrate a working Hiberate 5 application from Glassfish 4 to Glassfish 5.  Therefore we are attempting deployment in other JPA containers.

TomEE 7 is such a JPA container and we have Tomcat experience on our team.  However, the primary difference between Glassfish and TomEE seems to be the definition of the datasource via the an XML file in the WAR rather than defining it via an admin console.

Our attempt to configure said datasource is resulting in what seems to be the creation and linkage to our application, but then an immediate call to destroy the datasource which fails and unloads our application.

---

resources.xml =

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <resources>
  <Resource id="topazDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    jdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    jdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@dacracot.net:1521:DCCDB
    password = password
    passwordCipher = PlainText
    userName = topaz
  </Resource>
 </resources>
```

---

persistence.xml =

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="topazDB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>topazDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name" value="topaz"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path" value="hibernate-ehcache.xml" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_queries" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

catalina.out =

```
02-Aug-2018 08:01:59.702 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application archive [/Users/dacracot/Desktop/TopazDev/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/topaz.war]
02-Aug-2018 08:01:59.708 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /topaz
02-Aug-2018 08:01:59.710 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracting jar: /Users/dacracot/Desktop/TopazDev/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/topaz.war
02-Aug-2018 08:02:01.019 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracted path: /Users/dacracot/Desktop/TopazDev/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/topaz
02-Aug-2018 08:02:01.039 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
02-Aug-2018 08:02:09.714 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: /Users/dacracot/Desktop/TopazDev/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/topaz
02-Aug-2018 08:02:11.513 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=topaz/topazDS, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:11.518 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=topaz/topazDS)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:12.986 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:12.986 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.createContainer Auto-creating a container for bean topaz.Comp1690781744: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:12.987 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:12.998 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.core.managed.SimplePassivater.init Using directory /Users/dacracot/Desktop/TopazDev/tomee/temp for stateful session passivation
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.017 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'jdbc/topaz' in bean topaz.Comp1690781744 to Resource(id=topazDS)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.017 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/topaz/topazDS' in bean topaz.Comp1690781744 to Resource(id=topaz/topazDS)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.018 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/topazDS' in bean topaz.Comp1690781744 to Resource(id=topaz/topazDS)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.018 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy Configuring PersistenceUnit(name=topazDB, provider=org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.019 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.logAutoCreateResource Auto-creating a Resource with id 'topaz/topazDSNonJta' of type 'DataSource for 'topazDB'.
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.019 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy Configuring Service(id=topaz/topazDSNonJta, type=Resource, provider-id=topaz/topazDS)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.019 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=topaz/topazDSNonJta)
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.691 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.setJtaDataSource Adjusting PersistenceUnit topazDB <jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'topaz/topazDS' from 'topazDS'
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.691 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.setNonJtaDataSource Adjusting PersistenceUnit topazDB <non-jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'topaz/topazDSNonJta' from 'null'
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.705 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'javax.persistence.provider=org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence'
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.729 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "/Users/dacracot/Desktop/TopazDev/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/topaz" loaded.
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.734 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: /Users/dacracot/Desktop/TopazDev/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/topaz
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.761 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate PersistenceUnit(name=topazDB, provider=org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence) - provider time 1ms
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.761 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: /Users/dacracot/Desktop/TopazDev/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/topaz
02-Aug-2018 08:02:13.765 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/topaz]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:856)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1651)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1631)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:764)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2374)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1092)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:757)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1303)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

which version of hibernate did you add to tomee? Maybe ensure it is aligned on the JPA spec provided by TomEE (and you dont use a JPA 2.2 impl for the JPA 2.1 API for instance). Also, in some versions, hibernate has a chicken egg bug in its lifecycle between CDI and JPA so you can need to set the datasource as lazy (Lazy=true in its definition/properties).

Maybe also check logs/ folder, you should get a more precise reason for the error cause here it seems the application deployment is reverted cause of an issue which doesn't appear in the "out" log but should appear in log files.

Romain